# EE Solspace Freeform Pro Conditionals Not Working

Tags: solspace-freeform, solspace

I'm trying to add a conditional for a multipage form. On page 1 there is a radio button and depending on what the user selects, will depend on what fields will be displayed on page 2. Below is the template code and if you would like to see the live page, here's the link (www.igsmeetings.com/portal2014/index.php/meeting-registration). The question field that is acting as the conditional is a radio button "Do you plan on attending this meeting", and I have no idea what value I should use to call that information in my conditional tag. Please let me know what I am doing wrong.

**EE Version:** 2.7.4
**Freeform Pro Version:** 4.1.3

Thanks so much for your help!

```
{exp:freeform:form
   form_id="4"
   return="registration/confirmation"
   multipage="yes"
   multi_page_names="rsvp|complete"
   multi_page="{segment_3}"
   notify_admin="yes" 
   notify_user="yes"
   required="first_name|last_name|title|organization|email|phone_number|meeting_name|meeting_type|length_of_meeting|number_of_attendees|location|meeting_start_date_option_1|meeting_end_date_option_1"
   inline_errors="yes"
   inline_error_return="meeting-registration/{segment_3}#form"
   }

   {if freeform:error:first_name OR freeform:error:last_name OR freeform:error:title OR freeform:error:organization OR freeform:error:email OR freeform:error:phone_number OR freeform:error:meeting_name OR freeform:error:meeting_type OR freeform:error:length_of_meeting OR freeform:error:number_of_attendees OR freeform:error:location OR freeform:error:meeting_start_date_option_1 OR freeform:error:meeting_end_date_option_1}
                <div class="alert alert-danger">            
                    <i class="icon-warning-sign"></i> &nbsp;&nbsp;<strong>ALERT:</strong> There were error(s) in your form. Please correct the errors listed below.
                </div>
                {/if}
<!-- PAGE ONE -->
{freeform:page:1 required="rsvp"}
    <h4 class="color">Do you plan on attending this meeting?</h4><br />
     <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-7">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="inputAdminAsst" class="sr-only">{freeform:label:rsvp}</label>
                <div class="col-sm-12">
                  {freeform:field:rsvp attr:class="radio"}
                  {if freeform:error:rsvp}
                     <p class="text-danger"><i class="icon-asterisk"></i> {freeform:error:rsvp}</p>
                  {/if}
                </div>
             </div>
         </div>
      </div><!-- End Row  -->
      <hr>
     <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-2 col-md-offset10 pull-right">
            {freeform:submit attr:class="btn border-radius0 dark-gray-bg letters-white margin-top12" attr:value="Continue"}
        </div>
    </div>
{/freeform:page:1}

<!-------- PAGE TWO -------->
{freeform:page:2}
    <h4 class="color">Your Information</h4><br />
    {exp:user:stats}
    <form class="form-horizontal" role="form">


<!-- IF NO -->    
{if freeform:mp_data:rsvp == "freeform_rsvp_2"}

        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-4">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="inputFirstName" class="sr-only">{freeform:label:first_name}</label>
                    <div class="col-sm-12">
                      <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="First Name *" name="first_name" value="{first-name}">
                      {if freeform:error:first_name}
                         <p class="text-danger"><i class="icon-asterisk"></i> {freeform:error:first_name}</p>
                      {/if}
                    </div>
                 </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-4">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="inputLastName" class="sr-only">{freeform:label:last_name}</label>
                    <div class="col-sm-12">
                      <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Last Name *" name="last_name" value="{last-name}">
                      {if freeform:error:last_name}
                         <p class="text-danger"><i class="icon-asterisk"></i> {freeform:error:last_name}</p>
                      {/if}
                    </div>
                 </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-4">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="inputEmail" class="sr-only">{freeform:label:email}</label>
                    <div class="col-sm-12">
                      <input type="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Email *" name="email" value="{email}">
                      {if freeform:error:email}
                         <p class="text-danger"><i class="icon-asterisk"></i> {freeform:error:email}</p>
                      {/if}
                    </div>
                 </div>
             </div>
         </div><!-- End Row 1 -->
 <!-- /END IF NO -->         




<!-- IF YES -->
{if:else}

    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="inputFirstName" class="sr-only">{freeform:label:first_name}</label>
                <div class="col-sm-12">
                  <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="First Name *" name="first_name" value="{first-name}">
                  {if freeform:error:first_name}
                     <p class="text-danger"><i class="icon-asterisk"></i> {freeform:error:first_name}</p>
                  {/if}
                </div>
             </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="inputLastName" class="sr-only">{freeform:label:last_name}</label>
                <div class="col-sm-12">
                  <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Last Name *" name="last_name" value="{last-name}">
                  {if freeform:error:last_name}
                     <p class="text-danger"><i class="icon-asterisk"></i> {freeform:error:last_name}</p>
                  {/if}
                </div>
             </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="inputRankSalutation" class="sr-only">{freeform:label:rank_salutation}</label>
                <div class="col-sm-12">
                  <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Rank/Salutation *" name="rank_salutation">
                  {if freeform:error:rank_salutation}
                     <p class="text-danger"><i class="icon-asterisk"></i> {freeform:error:rank_salutation}</p>
                  {/if}
                </div>
             </div>
        </div>
     </div><!-- End Row 1 -->
     <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="inputTitle" class="sr-only">{freeform:label:title}</label>
                <div class="col-sm-12">
                  <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Title *" name="title" value="{user-title}">
                  {if freeform:error:title}
                     <p class="text-danger"><i class="icon-asterisk"></i> {freeform:error:title}</p>
                  {/if}
                </div>
             </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="inputOrganization" class="sr-only">{freeform:label:organization}</label>
                <div class="col-sm-12">
                  <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Organization *" name="organization" value="{organization}">
                  {if freeform:error:organization}
                     <p class="text-danger"><i class="icon-asterisk"></i> {freeform:error:organization}</p>
                  {/if}
                </div>
             </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="inputEmail" class="sr-only">{freeform:label:email}</label>
                <div class="col-sm-12">
                  <input type="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Email *" name="email" value="{email}">
                  {if freeform:error:email}
                     <p class="text-danger"><i class="icon-asterisk"></i> {freeform:error:email}</p>
                  {/if}
                </div>
             </div>
        </div>
     </div><!-- End Row 2 -->
     <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="inputCity" class="sr-only">{freeform:label:city}</label>
                <div class="col-sm-12">
                  <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="City *" name="city" value="{city}">
                  {if freeform:error:city}
                     <p class="text-danger"><i class="icon-asterisk"></i> {freeform:error:city}</p>
                  {/if}
                </div>
             </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="inputState" class="sr-only">{freeform:label:state}</label>
                <div class="col-sm-12">
                  {freeform:field:state attr:class="form-control"}
                  {if freeform:error:state}
                     <p class="text-danger"><i class="icon-asterisk"></i> {freeform:error:state}</p>
                  {/if}
                </div>
             </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="inputTelephone" class="sr-only">{freeform:label:phone_number}</label>
                <div class="col-sm-12">
                  <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Telephone *" name="phone_number" value="{telephone}">
                  {if freeform:error:phone_number}
                     <p class="text-danger"><i class="icon-asterisk"></i> {freeform:error:phone_number}</p>
                  {/if}
                </div>
             </div>
        </div>
     </div><!-- End Row 3 -->

     <hr>
     <h4 class="color">Administrative Assistant Information (if applicable)</h4><br />
     <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-7">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="inputAdminAsst" class="sr-only">{freeform:label:administrative_assistant_email}</label>
                <div class="col-sm-12">
                  {freeform:field:administrative_assistant_email attr:class="form-control" attr:placeholder="Administrative Assistant's Email"}
                  {if freeform:error:administrative_assistant_email}
                     <p class="text-danger"><i class="icon-asterisk"></i> {freeform:error:administrative_assistant_email}</p>
                  {/if}
                </div>
             </div>
         </div>
      </div><!-- End Row 4 -->
<!-- END IF YES -->      

     {/if}

<!-- END IF STATEMENT -->

     <hr>
     <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-2 col-md-offset10 pull-right">
            {freeform:submit attr:class="btn border-radius0 dark-gray-bg letters-white margin-top12" attr:name="Submit"}
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
{/exp:user:stats}
{/freeform:page:2}
{/exp:freeform:form}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of

```
{if freeform:mp_data:rsvp == "freeform_rsvp_2"}
```

...try:

```
{if '{freeform:mp_data:rsvp}' == "freeform_rsvp_2"}
```

Variables with `:` in them sometimes parse only when they have their brackets `{ }` present, which in turn often need to be wrapped in quotes when present in a conditional.